# What does this MYSQL image say? (Database Locks)

Tags: translation, terminology, database

I am reading a mysql article about different kind of locks and this image appeared:

[image]

Unfortunately, I cannot copy paste the words because it's in an image. I also don't know how to reproduce this with my keyboard.

If anyone could kindly translate this for me, would be very kind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Databases are not my main domain, but I double checked all terms. Here you go.

**Blue central box**

锁 = lock

**Green box**

| Box | ZH | EN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| main | 加锁机制 | lock engine |
| upper leaf | 乐观锁 | optimistic lock |
| lower leaf | 悲观锁 | pessimistic lock |

**Purple box**

| Box | ZH | EN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| main | 兼容性 | compatibility |
| upper leaf | 共享锁 | shared lock |
| lower leaf | 排他锁 | exclusive lock |

**Orange box**

| Box | ZH | EN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| main | 锁粒度 | lock granularity |
| upper leaf | 表锁 | table lock |
| middle leaf | 页锁 | page lock |
| lower leaf | 行锁 | row lock |

**Yellow box**

| Box | ZH | EN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| main | 锁模式 | lock mode |
| 1 | 记录锁 | record lock |
| 2 | gap锁 | gap lock |
| 3 | next-key锁 | next-key lock |
| 4 | 意向锁 | intention lock |
| 5 | 插入意向锁 | insert intention lock |